# Insert line in xml doc

Tags: c#, xml

I wanna insert in second line :

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

but I'm started to think that it is impossible.

Here is my base code:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();


                XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();


                doc.LoadXml("<results></results>");


                XmlNode newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);

                while (newNode != null)
                {
                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
                    newNode = doc.ReadNode(reader);

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Try like this

```
     XmlNode XNode = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("mso-application ", "progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"");
     doc.AppendChild(XNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` is a processing instruction not an element so you need to use the  [CreateProcessingInstruction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction.aspx)